# AWS mediaconvert throws [Failed probe/open: [No parser found for container]]

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-media-convert

I have created mediaconvert jobs to extract audio from video file, it was working fine and suddenly it just keeps throwing `[Failed probe/open: [No parser found for container]]`

even when I duplicate working jobs, they throw the same error

note, the files does exist and accessible

[image]

[image]

am using this settings

```
const Settings = {
    "TimecodeConfig": {
      "Source": "ZEROBASED"
    },
    "OutputGroups": [
      {
        "Name": "Audio File Group",
        "Outputs": [
          {
            "ContainerSettings": {
              "Container": "RAW"
            },
            "AudioDescriptions": [
              {
                "AudioSourceName": "Audio Selector 1",
                "CodecSettings": {
                  "Codec": "AAC",
                  "AacSettings": {
                    "Bitrate": 96000,
                    "CodingMode": "CODING_MODE_2_0",
                    "SampleRate": 48000
                  }
                }
              }
            ],
            "Extension": "wav"
          }
        ],
        "OutputGroupSettings": {
          "Type": "FILE_GROUP_SETTINGS",
          "FileGroupSettings": {
            "Destination": audioOutputPath
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "Thumbnail File Group",
        "Outputs": [
          {
            "ContainerSettings": {
              "Container": "RAW"
            },
            "VideoDescription": {
              "Width": 1280,
              "Height": 720,
              "CodecSettings": {
                "Codec": "FRAME_CAPTURE",
                "FrameCaptureSettings": {
                  "FramerateNumerator": 30,
                  "FramerateDenominator": 30,
                  "MaxCaptures": 1
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "OutputGroupSettings": {
          "Type": "FILE_GROUP_SETTINGS",
          "FileGroupSettings": {
            "Destination": thumbnailOutputPath
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "Inputs": [
      {
        "FileInput": inputFile,
        "AudioSelectors": {
          "Audio Selector 1": {
            "DefaultSelection": "DEFAULT"
          }
        },
        "VideoSelector": {},
        "TimecodeSource": "ZEROBASED"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems the issue was I added a line of code `fs.createReadStream(filePath)` which consumed the stream before being uploaded, eventhough the file looks like uploaded and I can see the full size on S3, but it was corrupted